# How to reliably accept time input in a Spring form?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, input, timepicker, spring-form

I have an `@Entity` with a few `java.util.Date` fields; two of those should be time formatted. I need a way to accept time, preferably with a picker, for persisting to my db.

I've tried to use, for example,

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="hh:mm a")
private Date startTime;
```

along with this, and various attempts at adding `type="time"` and so forth,

```
...
<label for="startTime" class="sr-only">Start</label>
<form:input path="startTime" name="startTime" placeholder="Start" /
...
```

...but I'm getting `Bad Request` errors.

I know what that means, I just need to know a reliable way to fix it. How can I reliably accept time input in a Spring form?

---

Additional Network info:

```
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/shift_create/1.html
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length:307
Content-Type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Mon, 10 Aug 2015 08:37:27 GMT
Server:Jetty(9.2.8.v20150217)
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:58
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=1w0rkel0w4eha96edvwq7rz1m
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/profile.html
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
name:ThisOne
shiftDate:08/13/2015
startTime:10:10 PM

Form data source : name=ThisOne&shiftDate=08%2F13%2F2015&startTime=10%3A10+PM
```

Comment: What is sent to server? Could you post the request?

Comment: Truthfully, @StanislavL, I don't know. I'm going the easy route and allowing Spring to do as much as possible. It's due to the fact that I went through the same thing with a true `Date`, and many tests with code swapping, that I know it's as simple as figuring out the "Spring" way to do it.

Comment: I could just take it as a string, provide a proxy, and write a parser, but I don't "want" to and I know I'm not the first one to need it. I also know I could add a date/time picker, but by the time the first time field is set the hard date, which corresponds to at least the start date, has been set. So I could but I'd want a way to select the correct date for them.

Comment: Definitely you have something in the startTime filed. What is the raw value of the field? You can just see request sent in e.g Chrome by pressing F12 and seeing network exchange. The same could be done in your favorite browser. The answer **how can I handle something on server?** is defined by the **something** sent from client.

Comment: @StanislavL- thanks! I c/p-ed the output on Chrome. FYI this is a time when I'm in the middle of trying fixes so this is taking, for example, "10:10 PM" as the way I typed it; the same results with a `type="time"` as well.

Comment: You can try to use **style = "-S"** or **style = "-SS"** instead of pattern in the @DateTimeFormat

Comment: @StanislavL, thanks; didn't work. Tried it with the input `type="time"` and not with both `-S` and `-SS` => `Bad Request`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get the time accepted turns out to be

1. Create a DTO class for the entity which needs to store time
2. Switch the type for the fields to `String`
3. Include a time picker for input (I used [ClockPicker](http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/))
4. Provide methods which parse the time strings according to your timepicker and `return` a `Date`
5. On `POST` use the methods from (4) to transfer the data from the DTO into the entity to be saved to the database

Most of the code is trivial; the parsing part might look like this:

```
// Time from a ClockPicker is "hh:mm"
private Date getTime(String time) {

    if (time != null)
        return makeCalendar(getTimeComponents(getTimeComponents(time))).getTime();
    return null;
}

private String[] getTimeComponents(String time) {
    return time.split(":");
}

private int[] getTimeComponents(String... time) {
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(time[0]);
    return new int[] { 
            hour, 
            Integer.parseInt(time[1]), 
            0, 
            hour >= PM ? Calendar.AM : Calendar.PM 
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `InitBinder` to your controller and specify the format that you want to get:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    sdf.setLenient(true);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(sdf,true));
}
```

Comment: Well, I've seen that before and from what I gather it's not the best way. I solved my date issue without it. In fact, having it prevented my code from working. So, at this point, this is actually (as far as I know) not good for me. Thanks.4

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils including an init binder will save you time since you won't have to solve the date issue everytime you have a form with a date issure.this is the best solution I know , can you plz post the answer to your question since you have already solved it

Comment: OK, I'll have to look into that then. The problem with it, I imagine, was due to redundant formats. So you're saying then I'd need an additional `SimpleDateFormat` for the inputs which I accept time in?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils no you just need to configure it one time for each controller.

Comment: Sorry; just wanting to be clear. I have, in the same controller and entity, another field of type `java.util.Date` that I annotate with `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")`. But the time field, although it is a date, would need like I have above in this post. So how can I provide a single `sdf` for both fields?